# InheritedWidget scope

Tags: flutter

So I have app with MaterialApp wrapped inside InheritedWidget called ApiProvider which provides API trough out application.Now what I want is to have InheritedWidget just for specific scope for example I want to login and have ProfileProvider which will be provided only if you user is logged in and etc.Is this doable ? Cause it doesn't make sense to have a Profile accessible or some other state that's in certain domain in this case authenticated user.

Comment: The scope is the descendants of `InheritedWidget`. (pages added by Navigator or popups are not descendants). You can also just add it or not depending on the logged-in status. `isLoggedIn ? MyInheritedWidget(child: MyApp()) : MyApp()`

Comment: @Guntee Bad idea. Conditionally wrapping a widget into another may destroy the state of the whole sub-tree.